# Two instances of Tor behave differently

Tags: socks, ubuntu, log

I have a local and a server instance. My task: Run multiple Tor instances.

On the local machine, I run Tor by means of command line:

```
tor --RunAsDaemon 1 --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" \
  --ControlPort 10001 --PidFile tor1.pid --SocksPort 9151 \
  --DataDirectory data/tor1
```

How I check Tor works:

1. I view the process list from `ps` command,
2. I do a curl request with SOCKS5 proxy.

For example, the command
`curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9151 http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com`
outputs my IP address.

On the server, I run my Tor instance using the same command. I can see it in the process list, but it didn't worked as proxy. When I do request from curl, it does not work, I don't get any output.

Maybe somehow I can view logs? In `/var/log/tor/` I find only run command.
When I run help on my local machine:

```
Jan 13 19:53:36.200 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6) running on Linux with
  Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
[…]
```

It reports that it is working with Libevent and OpenSSL library.

When I run same command on server machine, Tor writes:

```
Jan 13 21:01:42.563 [notice] Tor v0.2.3.25 (git-3fed5eb096d2d187) running on Linux.
[…]
```

It does not report about 2 libraries.

Questions:
How to setup full logging from command?
Why does my Tor instance on my server machine not work as a proxy?

Comment: Does Tor produce any output when you call curl at your server?

Comment: Answering your second question, the version of Tor on your server is older than the one running on your local machine. Get yourself a fresher copy of Tor and see if your problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

To setup full logging from command line add the following option:

```
--Log "notice file tor1.notice.log"
```

This says Tor should log on `notice` level to the file `tor1.notice.log` in the local directory. You can also use other log levels and file names as well as `stdout` for logging to your console.